# Fermionic subspace in a quantum harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, harmonic-oscillator

I have a bosonic harmonic oscillator with annihilation and creation operators $a$ and $a^\dagger$. These operators are defined with the position and momentum operators $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{P}$ and verify the usual commutation rules
$$ a = \hat{X} + i\hat{P}\text{ ,} \quad a^\dagger = \hat{X} - i\hat{P}$$
$$ [a,a^\dagger] = 1$$
In this bosonic Hilbert space, is there an operator $A$ and a state $|\psi\rangle$ that verify the following relations
$$ A|\psi\rangle = 0$$
$$ A^\dagger |\psi\rangle \neq 0 $$
$$ (A^\dagger)^2 |\psi\rangle = 0$$
In the subspace defined by $\text{Span}\left\{|\psi\rangle, A^\dagger |\psi\rangle\right\}$, the operator $A$ would then somehow act as a fermionic annihilation operator, with Fock states defined by $|0\rangle = |\psi\rangle$ and $|1\rangle = A^\dagger|\psi\rangle$.

I am able to find operators and states that verify the first two relations, but not the third. For instance using coherent states, we can have $|\psi\rangle = |\alpha\rangle$ and $A = a - \alpha$, but they do not verify $(A^\dagger)^2 |\psi\rangle = 0$.

Any tips, references or ideas to show that such objects exist (or not) and how to find them would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, "chopping up the Fock ladder" is a game that goes back to the mists of time: [Cigler 1979](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01319097.pdf), and Heisenberg's students, apocryphally to him!

[Here is a paper that reviews some of them](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0217732394000022) .
The basic idea is to terminate the rise of representations, in your case after two steps (but could be *n* ...).

Recall
$$
N=a^\dagger a , \qquad \leadsto ~~~ [N,a^\dagger]= a^\dagger
$$
whence, given the projection operator
$$
P_N ={1-(-)^N  \over 2}, \qquad  \leadsto ~~~ P_N^2= 1,
$$
take
$$
A^\dagger = P_N a^\dagger ,  \qquad  \leadsto ~~~ A= a P_N,\\
P_N P_{N+1}=0, \qquad P_N + P_{N+1}=1,
$$
so that
$$
A^{\dagger ~~2}=P_N a^{\dagger}  P_N a^{\dagger}= a^{\dagger}  P_{N-1}  P_N a^{\dagger} =0,
$$
when acting on the conventional integer ladder of states.

Further see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/96350/relation-between-representations-of-boson-operators/242352#242352).